# Selenium for iPhone emulator compile error

Tags: iphone, xcode, selenium, cocoahttpserver

when compiling the code for iWebDriver.xcodeproj I get the following error

> error: There is no SDK with the name or path
>   '/Users/sqaresources/svn_projcts/trunk/iphone/lib/buildtime-src/cocoahttpserver/iphonesimulator3.2'

the following warnings are also shown

> Missing SDK in target CocoaHTTPServer: iphonesimulator3.2 
>   Missing SDK in target CocoaHTTPServer: iphoneos3.1.2

I'm running OSX 10.7, Xcode 4.1

Please let me know if there is anything that I can do for this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve that problem, navigate to iphone-->lib-->buildtime-src-->cocoahttpserver-->CocoaHTTPServerLibrary.xcodeproj

Open CocoaHTTPServerLibrary.xcodeproj in your xcode (Make sure other instances are closed). And navigate to Build settings and change the 'BaseSDK' to 'Latest iOS(iOS4.3)'.

This should resolve the problem.....